# Ionic 2 camera not working on phone

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ionic2

I am relatively new to Ionic 2, Cordova & mobile. I followed a sample app to build a simple camera app. It is very similar to the code in a couple of other questions. Running on my android phone, the camera takes the picture but no image is displayed. The "takePicture fired" log entry displays but no further log entries. Is there something I am missing like a permission issue? Can't understand why I am not even seeing a log entry.

Relevant code:

mypage.html

```
<button ion-button block color="primary" (click)="takePicture()">Take   Picture</button>  
...

<img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />
```

mypage.ts

```
export class MyPage {

  public base64Image: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
}

    takePicture() {
    console.log("takePicture fired.");
    Camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      if (this.base64Image) {
        console.log("base64Image = " + this.base64Image);
      }
      else {
        console.log("base64Image = NULL");
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("An error occurred.");
      console.error(err);
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In your class.ts

```
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
```

Step 2: HTML

```
<img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" (click)="captureImage()"/>
```

Step 3:

```
captureImage(){

      Camera.getPicture({
                quality: 100,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                correctOrientation: false
                })
               .then((result) => {
                  this.base64Image = result;
                  console.log('Image URI: ' + this.base64Image);
               }, (error) => {
                console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
}
```

It's working fine...

Cheers!